Prove positivity of two symmetric polynomials in three variables over the reals, given a symmetric polynomial is positive
From a geometry problem
I have arrived at two polynomial inequalities in 3 real variables x1,x2,x3 that I would like to prove is true.
First I define 3 polynomials Delta,expr1,expr2 in x1,x2,x3
f=Simplify[(2 p^2 q s-4 p^2 r^2+p q^2 r+4 p r s+2 q r^2/. {p->SymmetricPolynomial[1,{z0,z1,z2,z3}],q->SymmetricPolynomial[2,{z0,z1,z2,z3}],r->SymmetricPolynomial[3,{z0,z1,z2,z3}],s->SymmetricPolynomial[4,{z0,z1,z2,z3}]}/.z0->((1-I x)/(1+I x))/(z1 z2 z3))(1+I x)^4];
Delta=Numerator[Factor[Factor[Discriminant[f,x]]/.{z1->((1-I x1)/(1+I x1)),z2->((1-I x2)/(1+I x2)),z3->((1-I x3)/(1+I x3))}]];
Clear[p,q,r,s];
{s,r,q,p}=Simplify[Drop[CoefficientList[f,x]/Coefficient[f,x^4],-1]/.{z1->((1-I x1)/(1+I x1)),z2->((1-I x2)/(1+I x2)),z3->((1-I x3)/(1+I x3))}];
expr1=FactorList[8q-3p^2][[-1,1]];
expr2=FactorList[-3 p^4+16 p^2 q-16 q^2-16 p r+64 s][[-1,1]];

I used NMinValue command to find the minimum of expr1 given the constraint Positive[Delta]:
NMinValue[{expr1,Positive[Delta]},{x1,x2,x3}]


So expr1 should be positive, given the constraint Positive[Delta].
I used NMinValue command to find the minimum of expr2 given the constraint Positive[Delta]:
NMinValue[{expr2,Positive[Delta]},{x1,x2,x3}]


So expr2 should be positive, given the constraint Positive[Delta].

Then I used Resolve command to prove the two inequalities expr1>0 && expr2>0 given the constraint Positive[Delta]:
Resolve[ForAll[{x1,x2,x3},Positive[Delta],Positive[expr1]],{x1,x2,x3}]

and
Resolve[ForAll[{x1,x2,x3},Positive[Delta],Positive[expr2]],{x1,x2,x3}]

But it is taking too long to compute, so I aborted the computation. Is there a better way to prove these polynomial inequalities? Thanks.

Note that expr1,expr2,Delta are all symmetric polynomials. I used SymmetricReduction command to rewrite them in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials s1,s2,s3 to get shorter expressions, but still taking too long to compute
Resolve[ForAll[{s1,s2,s3},Positive[Discriminant[x^3-s1 x^2+s2 x-s3,x]]&&Positive[SymmetricReduction[FactorList[Delta][[-1,1]],{x1,x2,x3},{s1,s2,s3}][[1]]],Positive[SymmetricReduction[expr1,{x1,x2,x3},{s1,s2,s3}][[1]]]]]

I used FindInstance command, but still taking too long to compute
FindInstance[{SymmetricReduction[expr1,{x1,x2,x3},{s1,s2,s3}][[1]]<=0,Discriminant[x^3-s1 x^2+s2 x-s3,x]>0,SymmetricReduction[FactorList[Delta][[-1,1]],{x1,x2,x3},{s1,s2,s3}][[1]]>0},{s1,s2,s3}]

